# Redirect only after $save success in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am POSTing a form and I want to redirect to my list page in case the form has no errors/is successfully persisted/saved to the db. How do I achieve that ?

```
app.controller('NoteCreateController',
  ['$scope', 'Note', '$routeParams', '$location','ShareNoteScope',
    function($scope, Note, $routeParams, $location, ShareNoteScope) {

    $scope.notes = ShareNoteScope.getScope().notes;

    $scope.newNote = {};

    $scope.createNote = function(note) {
      var newNote = new Note(note);
      newNote.$save(function(newNote) {
        $scope.notes.unshift(newNote.note);
        $scope.note = '';
        $scope.errors = '';
      }, function(newNote) {
        $scope.errors = newNote.data;
        // $location.path('/notes/'+newNote.note.id); where do I put this?
      });
    }
}]);
```

Comment: You want to change the path if the action is successful, right. So put the commented line in the success callback, instead of putting it in the error callback.

Comment: @JBNizet when does validation happen ? I am validating the form server-side in Rails, so If it is not valid and the $location.path is inside $save(), it will redirect which is wrong.

Comment: The first function you pass to $save() is called after the form has been posted, the server has validated it and done whatever it had to do, and sent back a success response. The second function passed to $save is called after the form has been posted, the server has validated it and done whatever it had to do, and sent back an error response.

Comment: I know but the current situation is that If the form is invalid/has errors, the $save is executed and the user is redirected without the item being persisted to the database. I want to redirect only in case the form is persisted to the database, so $save might be not "persist" but instead "try to save".

Comment: Make sure that your backend returns an error response (400-bad request is appropriate) is the sent form is invalid.

Comment: @JBNizet I haven't thought about this. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

`$save` wraps success call with a callback. The piece of code above should do the trick.

```
newNote.$save(function (newNote) {
    //success callback
    $location.path('/notes/' + newNote.note.id);

}, function (newNote) {
    $scope.errors = newNote.data;

});
```